# How to create a quality score in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I need to make quality score for cell in google which automatically give the results.
There are 3 columns

```
1. high quality 
2. medium quality 
3. low quality
```

High quality has `3` points and medium quality has `2` points and low quality has `1` point.
So if high quality column has 2 then it will get `3*2 = 6` and medium quality column has 3 then it will get `3*2 = 6`. And low quality column has 2 then it will get `2*1 =2`
So total quality score will be 6+6+2 = 14
So quality score column will be 14.

ie `quality score = [column e*3 + column f*2 + column g*1]`

[image: google sheet quality score creation]

Comment: https://www.alphr.com/copy-a-formula-down-column-google-sheets/

Answer (score 1):

You have already figure it. Simply use below formula to `H2` cell.

```
=E2*3+F2*2+G2*1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You have many options:**

- you can use [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en):

  **H2**: `=sum(E2*3,F2*2,G2*1)`

  [image]

---

- you can use [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en):

  **H2**: `=SUMPRODUCT({3,2,1},E2:G2)`

  [image]

---

- you can simply sum them up:

  **H2**: `=E2*3+F2*2+G2*1`

  [image]

Comment: No need `SUM()` as your summing by `+` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your screenshot, it looks to me you probably have more rows further down.

Instead of writing a formula for every single row you can use just one

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D2:D),(E2:E3+F2:F2+G2:G),""))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)